# Why are the keyframes for my texture not appearing in the f-curve window or dope sheet?

Tags: animation, texturing, compositing-nodes, keyframes

Why do keyframes on compositor node textures not show up in the F-Curve window and Dope Sheet?

[image]

Is it possible to access these keyframes in those windows?

Comment: you might have to upload the .blend to pasteall.org so someone can figure out what's going on in your .blend file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Texture keyframes don't always appear in the dopesheet:

[image]

If the texture is used by an object in the scene, it'll show up in the dopesheet:

[image]

Using the texture in an input texture node in the compositor will not make it show up in the dope sheet (unless it's also used by an object in the scene):

[image]

Comment: Since I only wanted the texture in the compositor, I just used it in a dummy mesh an put it in a spare layer.